# Local server testing

Tags: javascript, html, express, server, localhost

## Hey guys, need some help if possible-

I have a webpage and an express server. All works okay on my laptop using touchscreen. The issue is, when I run a live server and access the webpage through my phone, it seems like the server requests just don't happen. I have added CORS origin to my devices IP and configured the event listener so it takes touch events. Is there something else I'm missing?

## Server:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const PORT = 4001;

app.use(cors({ origin: ['vscode IP and port', 'MY phones IP'] }));

app.get('/test', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send({ test: 'testing' });
});

app.listen(PORT, (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(`Runnning on port: ${PORT}`);
})
```

## JS:

```
const h1 = document.querySelector('#testh1');
const p = document.querySelector('p');

h1.addEventListener('touchstart', async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4001/test');
    const jsonResponse = await response.json();
    p.innerHTML = jsonResponse.test
});
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks

This is just a test before I implement into my actual project.

The webpage has a button which you click, Then it displays the object value from the response.

Works fine on my laptop where it is running but not from my phone

Comment: Fetching `http://localhost:4001/test` on your phone assumes there's a web server running on your phone.

Comment: @tevemadar is correct, if your exposing the JS from said same express App, just do -> `/test` the `http(s)://domain:port` is then implicit.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is with localhost. Localhost will ONLY be accessible from your laptop because it is technically the laptops internal network. This is also true for the phone, so referencing localhost never actually reaches outside the device.

Your phone has no way to connect to it. One solution is to tunnel localhost out to the public internet using ngrok: https://ngrok.com/

install ngrok, then do `ngrok http http://localhost:<yourt-port>`, this will then give you back a public address you can use. Be aware, this is a PUBLIC web address, so be sure to not expose any sensitive data. Also the address will change every time the tunnel is restarted.

UPDATE Method #2 (from Keith):

You can also connect to the server running on your laptop (provided they are on the same network) by updating the URL on the phone to be http://:/test

Be aware that if you have any sort of firewall configured (particularly on windows) it may block this connection.

Comment: No need to tunnel out to the public, the OP can connect to the laptop internally.  But `ngrok` certainly handy if you want a quick way to put something public.

Comment: @keith helpful to note! Does this require a direct connection to the phone? OP could expose a port on the LAN, but thats funnily more complicated than public haha

Comment: Ah I now see you mean via IP address. I block incoming traffic by default, so use ngrok as a quick way around it.

Comment: If you use a router, there is no need to block incoming traffic, generally connecting locally you normally have IP's like `192.168.1.22` etc, these are known as protected internal networks, there automatically fire-walled to the outside world.  Unless your worried about other computers in your own home connecting to your own computers, then blocking the ports is pointless, and just makes internal network management like shares / NAS / MQTT brokers, and of course your own HTTP servers, etc more complicated than they need to be.  Personally I have all OS based firewalls turned off.

Comment: Yea agreed on it making more complicated, but am frequently on shared networks or a large office wifi network shared between companies (not great I know). I haven't found it that bad actually, since the vast majority of dev I'm doing is all dockerized on laptop, with the occasional port that needs to be exposed to test on a phone.

Comment: Yeah, good point about it been laptop, and connecting to other networks.  Firewall then makes good sense,..

Answer (score 0):

I am going to elaborate a bit more on what @tevemadar says... When you run your node server on your laptop, localhost is *local* to the machine you're running that server on. Trying to access the same localhost from your phone as you do on your laptop is not going to happen from that sense.

If youre wanting to access the laptop localhost from another device you can use a tool like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/docs/getting-started/).

Comment: Or just access the laptops IP directly, `ngrok` is just a simple way to make the app visible to the public.